# Invalid type tf.complex64 for tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()

Tags: tensorflow, complex-numbers, gradient-descent

I am working with complex neural networks. I have created a network that works correctly using:

```
[...]
gradients = tf.gradients(mse, [weights])[0]
training_op = tf.assign(weights, weights - learning_rate * gradients)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(training_op)
```

Now when I try to use:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(mse)
```

I get, for line `training_op = optimizer.minimize(mse)` the following:

```
ValueError: Invalid type tf.complex64 for weights:0, expected: [tf.float32, tf.float64, tf.float16, tf.bfloat16].
```

Is this truly not supported for complex? Or am I doing something wrong? I tried the same with real-valued net and it worked correctly so I believe I have the structure correct.

---

New insight:

According to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize). 
Minimize is divided into two parts:

1. `compute_gradients`
2. `apply_gradients`

If we test them separately, the error occurs on the `compute_gradients` method.

So running `tf.gradients` work but running `optimizer.compute_gradients` doesn't? This is getting weirder. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: There is some discussion about this in [this (old) issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3032). It seems the suggestion is that, since optimizers do not currently support complex types (even if complex gradients are supported, as you mention), you may just use separate variables for real and imaginary parts. You may also consider writing your own optimizer and override the [`_valid_dtypes`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L903-L912) method (I don't know what other changes might be necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the answer here from the comment section for the benefit of the community.

Since optimizers do not currently support complex types (even if complex gradients are supported, as you mention), you may just use separate variables for real and imaginary parts. You may also consider writing your own optimizer and override the `valid_dtypes` method like the below example.

```
def complex_mul_real( c, r ):
    return tf.complex(tf.real(c)*r, tf.imag(c)*r)
```

Further, detailed discussion on this topic could be found on this [Github issue.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2255)